# Dragging a selected hyperlink to cut/paste in a comment doesn't work

Tags: support, hyperlinks

When adding or editing a question or comment, if I select the text of a URL and drag/drop it, as if to move it somewhere else in the comment, the pasted URL is shortened to just the domain, losing any specificity it had.

Some examples:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/285610/mbomb007 becomes "mbomb007"

http://caniuse.com/#feat=let becomes "caniuse.com"

Is this functionality intended? It's very annoying.

Comment: Not something we are doing. This is either the browser you are using or some plugin/add-on you have installed.

Comment: @Oded browser, I observe the same behavior with vanilla Chrome with no plugins/add-ons whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This got nothing to do with Stack Exchange, it's just the way your browser behaves. (Likely Chrome?)

As a proof, try it in [this plain fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rpynfm1/1/).

Comment: Oh, so it is. That sucks. I guess I should report this to their support instead.